# How to hide, disable calendar list item fields in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, list, permissions, calendar, hide

I want to hide or make some fields read only on editform.aspx. I follwed the example on this [page](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-5-Customize_the_-and-quot;NewFormaspx-and-quot;_page_for_a_SharePoint_List.aspx), but without deliting the "original" webpart list. I hide the original webpart and created a new custom list from the original list. Then i was able to apply xsl on the custom list to hide or to make the field "read only". Unfortunately the recurring events stopped working or where totaly messed up. Some times i've got error messages when I clicked on specific event in calendar view. The calendar list works fine and the fields are hidden or disabled in "Edit mode" when the event is not recurring. My question is. Is there any other way to hide or disable the items for specific security group or sharepoint group on calendar list?

Comment: I've removed the link on this post (a large number of spam flags were being accurred).  If anyone wants to see the link, please check the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

If SharePoint Designer is an option, then this [blog post from Laura Rogers](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3) shows how you can display SharePoint fields by permission level. It should work with a calendar list.

This will give you complete control over the solution without the need for a third-party product.

Comment: I tried her method to. Unfortunately the recurring events stopped working or where totaly messed up. I decided to buy SharePoint List Forms Extensions. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @ArtSerebryakov Thanks, that's fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think it is little bit hard to do that. Otherwise there should be not so much such third party tools like [SharePoint Column View Permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html), Bamboo also has such tool.

Take a look at this if you want make it happen through code [stackoverflow.com/questions/1058232](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058232). But I am not sure it works in calender.

Answer (score 0):

Two tools I've run across to do what you're looking for:

- [SPListDisplaySetting](http://www.codeplex.com/SPListDisplaySetting) - "SharePoint feature (for WSS 3.0 and MOSS) providing advanced settings to customize list form rendering in new, display and edit mode."

You can specify that certain fields only show up on edit, new, or display pages and only for certain groups, or to hide them completely.

My only problem with this is that the installer doesn't quite work.  However, a user has [posted working instructions on the discussion board](http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=52388).

- [SharePoint Tool Basket - List Columns Manager](http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SharePoint%20-%20List%20Columns%20Manager) - "This feature allows site collection administrators to view all the columns of a list including hidden/read-only ones and gives column details such as the internal name, Guid, Type.."

Comment: I've looked at SPListDisplaySetting and read the comments. I think the program has to many issues to be used on production enviroment. Did you however had any issues with SPListDisplaySetting?

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty nice solution at [Cleverworkarounds](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/03/13/free-mosswss-2007-web-part-hide-controls-via-javascript/). The code is writen in javascript so the script does not actually remove the fields, which in my case is necessery, but it does hide the fields. Me, I need to stick to SharePoint List Form Extensions due to some sensitive data our customers have and want to be remove for some users. Laura Rogers solutions is good too, but with Cleverworkarounds you don't need to use Sharepoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to download the Sharepoint Manager from CodePlex. Install it on the server (it uses the object model) and you get simple access to a whole heap of stuff including, on a per-field-per-list basis, whether a specific column is hidden in it's entirety (even from the list settings), or hidden from the display form, the edit form or both. It's a matter of setting a true/false dropdown and clicking save. There is also the option for making columns readonly too.

It's all or nothing in terms of permissions though - whatever you choose applies to everyone who can access that area.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide items in the calendar list using JQuery. Please follow the steps below:
- From the Calendar tab Customize List category select -> Form Web Parts -> Default New Form
- Select the Insert tab and from Web Parts category -> click Web Part.
- Choose Media and Content, then choose Content Editor and click Add.
- Place the Content Editor below your form and click inside the Content Editor
- Click on Format Text tab -> Markup category -> Click on HTML -> Edit HTML Source
Add the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("td.ms-dttimeinput").hide();  
$("span[title='All Day Event'] > input").attr("checked","checked");
$("tr:has(span[title='Recurrence'])").not("tr:has(tr)").hide(); 
$("tr:has(span[title='All Day Event'])").not("tr:has(tr)").hide();
$("tr:has(span[title='Workspace'])").not("tr:has(tr)").hide();
});
</script>
```

The above code also puts the "All Day Event" to be checked true.
Hope this would be useful ..

Comment: it worked now , actually jquery file was missing.
     <script src=”//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js”></script>
     <script type=”text/javascript”>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(‘nobr:contains(“All Day Event”)’).closest(‘tr’).hide();
$(‘nobr:contains(“Recurrence”)’).closest(‘tr’).hide();
});
</script>