# Managing specific document access depending on a users permissions or role they belong too

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a custom Document Library in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058232/creating-a-custom-document-library-in-sharepoint)

I have 2 users, Martin and John

I have 5 documents, all available to Martin and John. I also have 2 documents that are available to John only (Martin must not see them). To complicate matters these documents should replace 2 of the existing documents from the original 5 - so that only 5 documents are ever displayed to Martin or John.

John must not be able to see the original 2 documents that have been replaced. A small amount of luck is that an administrator will specify which new document should ‘replace’ an existing document from the originals. Over time I would be required to add more documents and and users, providing the same functionality of ‘replacing’ certain documents for certain users.

How would you do this?

My first thought was creating roles and configuring the roles on each individual document; I could add and remove these roles depending on whether Martin or John should be able to see that document. I think this would get really, really complicated. What other approach could I try?

Any solution has to be security trimmed for the all important search function!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered here [Creating a custom Document Library in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058232)